# Don't force HTTPS on the signup page until the CAPTCHA can be loaded under HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, captcha, ssl

When trying to sign up for an account on Meta, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/signup is forcibly redirected to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

The CAPTCHA fails to load under HTTPS, so you need to tell your browser to load insecure content. Actually, you need to find out first why there is no CAPTCHA visible to begin with, causing the form to yell at you for not filling in the CAPTCHA.

This also fails on other sites, but you need to go to that page manually. The menu currently sends you to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login#create-account

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10539837/1015495

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library we use is supposed to "know" whether it is on a secure connection or not, however, because of how we do SSL termination, the library is misinformed.

The captcha is only displayed on rare occasions which is why I have missed this so far - sorry about that.

I have implemented an override to ensure that when you use an https connection the correct https URL is emitted for the google apis.

This has been deployed and works as expected.

You can test this out on:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha (SSL)

and

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha (no SSL)